# Are there any downsides of invokable factories?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, factory

Are there any downsides of invokable factories? For example:

```
class EntityFactory
{
    protected $map = [
        'User' => User::class,
    ];        

    public function __invoke(string $entity, ...$args)
    {
        if (! $class = $this->map[$entity] ?? null) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Unknown entity "%s"', $entity));
        }

        return new $class(...$args);
    }
}
```

And later:

```
$entityFactory = new EntityFactory;
$john = $entityFactory('User', 'John');
$jane = $entityFactory('User', 'Jane');
```

Am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: Code clarity, unless you call your factory `createUser` or `newUser` or something that describes the intention better .